# Best multiprocessing practice for a dependent loop nested inside another loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is a pretty basic question but my understanding of multiprocessing is not great. I have a program that has two generators, both of which generate a very long iterable. My code is of the form

```
def generator1()
    # Do heavy computations and yield objects

def generator2(results1)
    for result in results1:
        # Do heavy computations and yield objects

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for result in generator2(generator1()):
        # Do some checks. If result is what we want, then terminate the program.
```

Even though both generators might take longer than the universe's lifespan to terminate, theoretically it should take much less time to obtain a result that I'm looking for.

Ideally I would like n jobs to run generator2 with the first result from generator1, then n jobs to run with the second result, etc, as and when generator1 yields results. What is the best way to do this? I have been playing around with Queues and Processes, but I'm confused as to what approach I should be using.

---

**Original post:**
For simplicity, let's say we have the following code:

```
from random import random


def generator1():
    for _ in range(int(1e100)):
        yield random()


def generator2(args):
    num1, num2 = args

    for i in range(int(1e100)):
        yield hash(str(num1**num2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num1 in generator1():
        for num2 in generator1():
            for result in generator2((num1, num2)):
                ...
```

I would like to use multiprocessing in the code. I suppose a very simple way to do it would be something like

```
import multiprocessing as mp

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.imap(generator2, 
                            ((num1, num2) for num1 in generator1() for num2 in generator1()))
        for r in results:
            ...
```

... but ideally I would like `generator2` with *different* values for `num1` to be run simultaneously. For example, suppose I would like 2 processes to work on arguments `(num1_a, ...)`, 2 of them to work on arguments `(num1_b, ...)`, etc. I'm confused as to what approach I should use: should I be using different processes, or something like `pool.apply_async()` etc?

Comment: Your code using multiprocessing cannot work because you *" ... cannot pickle a 'generator' object"".  `generator2` needs to *return* its results, not *yield* them (and why are all the 1e100 duplicate hash values being computed?). You can offer *simplicity* but combine that with some reality. Would a program that submits 1e10000 tasks to generate 1e1000000 values terminate before the sun burns out? **What are the *real* numbers?** Also,  `int(1e100) != int(str('1' + '0' * 100))` because of the inherent (lack of) precision with floating point. **Is your real code using random numbers?**

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my post to focus on the crux of the issue. Is it a better question new?

Comment: I will have to read this more closely to see if I have more questions and that won't be until tomorrow (there may be many others who can assist you in the meanwhile) -- but it appears to be clearer if I am free to ignore your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping to be able to ignore your original post, but I believe that it has important details that need to be considered. I also hope that the following is not too overwhelming:

1. You are generating potentially a very large number of tasks to be computed in parallel, so many in fact that the program would run until doomsday before all the calculations have completed.
2. You are expecting one of the calculations (more than one?) to yield a result that will cause you to stop doing any more calculations.

With that as my premise, this is how I would proceed:

First, let's observe that in your non-multiprocessing code you had:

```py
def generator1():
    for _ in range(int(1e100)):
        yield random()

... # Code omitted:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num1 in generator1():
        for num2 in generator1():
            for result in generator2((num1, num2)):
                ....
```

It seems to me that instead of iterating `generator1` twice, you can iterate just once if you rewrite the code as follows:

```py
def generator1():
    for _ in range(int(1e100)):
        num1 = random()
        for _ in range(int(1e100)):
            num2 = random()
            yield num1, num2

... # Code omitted:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for num1, num2 in generator1():
        for result in generator2((num1, num2)):
            ...
```

To make it clearer how things work, I will be making the following changes:

1. My `generator1` will only be iterating each loop N times where N has been set to 4.
2. Rather than producing two random numbers, I will be generating for input tuples as follows:

```py
for num1 in range(N):
    for num2 in range(N):
        # Generate (num1, num2)
```

3. Likewise `generator2` will complete its calculation by also iterating values `num3` in the range `0..N-1`.
4. The results that `generator2` will generate will be `num1 ** num2 + num3`, instead of a hash of a string in order for the program to produce repeatable results.

You will, of course, modify the above to fit your actual problem.

I am assuming that each tuple that `generator1` is producing is relatively inexpensive to produce (e.g. random numbers) since you were not attempting to use use multiprocessing in your original solution that used `multiprocessing.pool.imap`. Also, since `imap` returns a task's results in the order in which the task was submitted to the pool, but the method I will be using does not guarantee an order, I will also be returning the three values that went into the result calculation.

`generator1` instead of being an actual generator will be a process that now write its tuples to a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. If there are `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` processors available and `generator1` is running on one of them, that leaves `n_processes = multiprocesing.cpu_count() - 1` as the number of processes executing `generator2` getting tuples from the queue and generating the final results. These results get written to a second output queue. When `generator1` has no more tuples to generate (which presumably will be when hell freezes over in your real-world case, but not in my demo), it will write `n_processes` *sentinel* items (the value `None`) to its queue signifying that no more data will be produced by this process. So when each of the `n_processes` retrieves the sentinel item instead of a tuple, it will terminate. Likewise, each of the `n_processes` processes will before terminating write a sentinel value to the output result queue so that when the main process has retrieved all `n_processes` sentinel items it knows that there is no more data coming and it too can terminate.

The reality of your situation is, however, that when the main process retrieves a result created by `generator2` that satisfies some termination criteria, the main process will just terminate all the other running processes. `generator2` presumably also knows what a satisfactory result is and should not even bother outputting unsatisfactory results. Again, for demo purposes, I have `generator2` putting to the output queue *all* results and the main process running until all results have been retrieved and printed.

This is the basic idea:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count

N = 4

def generator1(tuples_queue: Queue, n_processes: int) -> None:
    for num1 in range(N):
        for num2 in range(N):
            tuples_queue.put((num1, num2))

    for _ in range(n_processes):
        # show generator2 there is no more data:
        tuples_queue.put(None) # show no more data

def generator2(tuples_queue: Queue, results_queue: Queue) -> None
    # Loop until tuples_queue.get() returns None:
    for t in iter(tuples_queue.get, None):
        num1, num2 = t
        value = num1 ** num2
        for num3 in range(N):
            result = value + num3
            # In addition to putting the result, we also for demo
            # purposes put the 3 input values used to get the result:
            results_queue.put((num1, num2, num3, result)) # Show no more data

    results_queue.put(None) # Show no more data from this process


def main():
    n_processes = cpu_count() - 1

    # Queue of finite size because generator1 can generate values
    # faster than generator2 can process them:
    tuples_queue = Queue(n_processes)
    results_queue = Queue()


    p1 = Process(target=generator1, args=(tuples_queue, n_processes))
    p1.start()

    # rest of the processes to work on output from generator1:
    processes = [
        Process(target=generator2, args=(tuples_queue, results_queue))
        for _ in range(n_processes)
    ]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # Get the results:
    seen_end_count = 0
    while seen_end_count < n_processes:
        t = results_queue.get()
        if t is None:
            seen_end_count += 1
        else:
            num1, num2, num3, result = t
            # Is this a result we want to terminate on?
            if False:
                # Got the result we want
                print(f'num1 = {num1}, num2 = {num2}, num3 = {num3}, result = {result}', flush=True)
                # Terminate:
                break
            else:
                # Normally we would not want to display results
                # we are not intetested in, but we do so here for demo purposes:
                print(f'num1 = {num1}, num2 = {num2}, num3 = {num3}, result = {result}', flush=True)

    # Kill the processes
    p1.terminate()
    for p in processes:
        p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Prints:

```None
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 0
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 0
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 3
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 0
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 1
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 9
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 10
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 11
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 12
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 2
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 3
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 5
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 5
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 6
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 7
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 8
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 9
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 10
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 11
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 3
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 4
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 5
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 6
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 27
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 28
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 29
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 30
```

You can see that results are not generated in task submission order. If we sort the output, we get:

```None
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 0
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 3
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 0
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 3
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 0
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 1
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 2
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 2
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 3
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 5
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 4
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 5
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 6
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 7
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 8
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 9
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 10
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 11
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 3
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 4
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 5
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 6
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 9
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 10
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 11
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 12
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 27
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 28
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 29
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 30
```

Some final points:

1. The `generator1` process can presumably generate the tuples that are input to the `generator2` processes much faster than the `generator2` processes can generate results. On that assumption the queue of tuples can potentially grow extremely large and you will run out of memory. Therefore we throttle `generator1` by putting a size on how big the tuples queue can grow before `generator1` is blocked until a tuple is taken off the queue. I have set that value to be `n_processes`.
2. There is a distinction between the number of logical cores returned by the call `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` and the number of physical cores you actually have. See [So what are logical cpu cores (as opposed to physical cpu cores)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88283/so-what-are-logical-cpu-cores-as-opposed-to-physical-cpu-cores). My desktop has 2 logical cores for every physical core. If your multiprocessing task is 100% CPU (e.g. it never waits for I/O or network requests to complete), which is the case in my demo (except for the print statements), then my experience has been that your multiprocessing level should be the number of physical cores instead of the number of logical cores. So in my case I probably should have used:

```py
n_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() // 2 - 1
```

3. When you use the `multiprocessing.pool.map` method, if you do not specify a *chunksize* argument one will be computed based on the size of the iterable being passed and the pool size. This is because when the iterable is large, as in your case, fewer but larger task queue puts and gets is more efficient and can reduce the running time. This code essentially uses a chunk size of 1 and may not be the most efficient. But if we were to do our own chunking by having `generator1` write to the tuples queue a list of `chunksize` tuples for some appropriate value of `chunksize` and `generator2` iterates the tuple retrieved, then we have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count

N = 4
CHUNKSIZE = 4 # 4 chunks of size 4

def generator1(tuples_queue: Queue, n_processes: int) -> None:
    chunk = []
    for num1 in range(N):
        for num2 in range(N):
            chunk.append((num1, num2))
            if len(chunk) == CHUNKSIZE:
                tuples_queue.put(chunk)
                chunk = []
    # Any small chunk left over?
    if chunk:
        tuples_queue.put(chunk)

    # We cannot chunk up the sentinels (1 per generator2 process):
    for _ in range(n_processes):
        # show generator2 there is no more data:
        tuples_queue.put([None]) # show no more data

def generator2(tuples_queue: Queue, results_queue: Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        chunk = tuples_queue.get()
        if len(chunk) == 1 and chunk[0] is None:
            break;
        for num1, num2 in chunk:
            value = num1 ** num2
            for num3 in range(N):
                result = value + num3
                # In addition to putting the result, we also for demo
                # purposes put the 3 input values used to get the result:
                results_queue.put((num1, num2, num3, result)) # Show no more data

    results_queue.put(None) # Show no more data from this process
... # Rest of code unmodified
```

I have not chunked the results queue since in your actual situation I would think you are only writing "satisfactory" results.

**Update**

You said in your original post, "For example, suppose I would like 2 processes to work on arguments (num1_a, ...), 2 of them to work on arguments (num1_b, ...), etc." Then the following should accomplish this. Note that I am also returning back to the main process the process id of the process that produced the solution to demonstrate what process is working on what and I have added a call to 'time.sleep' to simulate processing time required in `generator2` to generate a result:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count, current_process

N = 4

def generator1(tuples_queue: Queue, n_processes: int) -> None:
    half_N = N // 2
    for num1 in range(N):
        tuples_queue.put((num1, 0, half_N))
        tuples_queue.put((num1, half_N, N))

    for _ in range(n_processes):
        # show generator2 there is no more data:
        tuples_queue.put(None) # show no more data

def generator2(tuples_queue: Queue, results_queue: Queue) -> None:
    import time

    pid = current_process().pid
    # Loop until tuples_queue.get() returns None:
    for t in iter(tuples_queue.get, None):
        num1, start, end = t
        for num2 in range(start, end):
            value = num1 ** num2
            for num3 in range(N):
                time.sleep(.1)
                result = value + num3
                # In addition to putting the result, we also for demo
                # purposes put the 3 input values used to get the result:
                results_queue.put((num1, num2, num3, result, pid)) # Show no more data

    results_queue.put(None) # Show no more data from this process


def main():
    n_processes = cpu_count() - 1

    # Queue of finite size because generator1 can generate values
    # faster than generator2 can process them:
    tuples_queue = Queue(n_processes)
    results_queue = Queue()


    p1 = Process(target=generator1, args=(tuples_queue, n_processes))
    p1.start()

    # rest of the processes to work on output from generator1:
    processes = [
        Process(target=generator2, args=(tuples_queue, results_queue))
        for _ in range(n_processes)
    ]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # Get the results:
    seen_end_count = 0
    while seen_end_count < n_processes:
        t = results_queue.get()
        if t is None:
            seen_end_count += 1
        else:
            num1, num2, num3, result, pid = t
            # Is this a result we want to terminate on?
            if False:
                # Got the result we want
                print(f'num1 = {num1}, num2 = {num2}, num3 = {num3}, result = {result}, pid = {pid}', flush=True)
                # Terminate:
                break
            else:
                # Normally we would not want to display results
                # we are not intetested in, but we do so here for demo purposes:
                print(f'num1 = {num1}, num2 = {num2}, num3 = {num3}, result = {result}, pid = {pid}', flush=True)

    # Kill the processes
    p1.terminate()
    for p in processes:
        p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 8184
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 4, pid = 10076
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 0, pid = 14180
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 1492
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 16716
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 15092
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 8184
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 1, pid = 14180
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 15092
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 16716
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 1492
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 5, pid = 10076
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 8184
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 2, pid = 14180
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 16716
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 6, pid = 10076
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 1492
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 15092
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 8184
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 3, pid = 14180
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 16716
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 1492
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 7, pid = 10076
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 15092
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 0, pid = 8184
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 0, pid = 14180
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 8, pid = 10076
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 15092
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 16716
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 2, pid = 1492
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 3, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 1, pid = 8184
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 3, pid = 1492
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 16716
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 15092
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 9, pid = 10076
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 1, pid = 14180
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 4, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 2, pid = 8184
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 2, pid = 14180
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 10, pid = 10076
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 15092
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 4, pid = 1492
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 16716
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 5, pid = 9456
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 3, pid = 8184
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 5, pid = 1492
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 11, pid = 10076
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 16716
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 3, pid = 14180
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 15092
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 6, pid = 9456
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 9, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 10, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 11, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 12, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 27, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 28, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 29, pid = 8184
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 30, pid = 8184
```

The above sorted:

```None
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 0, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 1, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 2, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 3, pid = 14168
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 0, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 1, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 2, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 3, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 0, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 1, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 2, pid = 11408
num1 = 0, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 3, pid = 11408
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 19648
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 10948
num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 10948
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 2, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 3, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 4, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 5, pid = 9208
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 4, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 5, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 6, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 7, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 8, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 9, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 10, pid = 14308
num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 11, pid = 14308
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, result = 1, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 1, result = 2, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 2, result = 3, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 0, num3 = 3, result = 4, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 0, result = 3, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 1, result = 4, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 2, result = 5, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 3, result = 6, pid = 18624
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 0, result = 9, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 1, result = 10, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 2, result = 11, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, result = 12, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 0, result = 27, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 1, result = 28, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 2, result = 29, pid = 11408
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, num3 = 3, result = 30, pid = 11408
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed answer, this works beautifully

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't easily have what you'd like, some kind of multiprocessing enabled generator that automatically hands over tasks between generators. This can be done with `asyncio` but then you don't get all the nice performance advantages of `multiprocessing` because it all runs in one thread.

In my experience you'll want more robust control over how the processes interact with each other and hand over work to individual worker processes.

This requires heavy usage of [`multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue),[`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Event) and creates a subclass of [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) to implement some separation between domain code and multiprocessing.

```
import queue
from multiprocessing import Process, Event, JoinableQueue

from stack_domain import generator1, generator2, create_tuple


class QueueConsumingProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, input_queue, output_queue, abort, fn):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_queue = input_queue
        self.output_queue = output_queue
        self.abort = abort
        self.domain_function = fn

    def run(self):
        while not self.abort.is_set():
            try:
                data = self.input_queue.get(True, 1)
                print(f"Got data {data}")
                for result in self.domain_function(data):
                    self.output_queue.put(result)
                self.input_queue.task_done()
                print("task done")
            except queue.Empty:
                continue
```

You need to put your domain functions in a separate file, or it won't be serializable:

```
from random import random


def generator1():
    print('called')
    for _ in range(10):
        yield random()


def create_tuple(data: int):
    for num in generator1():
        yield (data, num)


def generator2(args):
    num1, num2 = args
    print('gen2')
    for i in range(10):
        yield str(num1) + str(num2) + str(i)
```

And then use it

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    functions = [create_tuple, generator2]
    queues = [JoinableQueue(1500) for _ in range(len(functions) + 1)] 

    abort = Event() # Termination event, is shared across processes
    consumers = []
    
    for i, f in enumerate(functions): #Hook up queues and create consumers
        input_queue = queues[i]
        output_queue = queues[i + 1]
        consumer = QueueConsumingProcess(input_queue, output_queue, abort, f)
        consumers.append(consumer)

    input_queue = queues[0]
    output_queue = queues[-1]
    for num in generator1(): # Feed first queue
        input_queue.put(num)
        
    for c in consumers: # Start all consumers after we feed the data, or *race condition*
        c.start()

    results = []

    for q in queues[:-1]:
        q.join() # Wait until everyone except output is done
    abort.set() # Send the shutdown signal to processes
    while True: # Consume output queue
        try:
            data = output_queue.get(True,1)
            results.append(data)
        except queue.Empty:
            break

    print(results)
```

Output

```
['0.362263286686698050.43869637987082320', '0.362263286686698050.65452132195757220', '0.362263286686698050.0602892053944352750',
 ...
'0.0234849575861264540.72618086690473450']
```

You can adjust the code to hook up multiple consumers to each `Queue`.

Honestly though, you will make mistakes with `multiprocessing` code eventually and you'll be hunting lost tasks along the way and face deadlocks if your complexity is sufficient. Dealing with Exceptions in the domain functions also requires additional `multiprocessing` code and possibly more queues.

You're likely better off handing this over to [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/), which has very robust code to store data in a distributed fashion and assign tasks to workers, keep them alive, and resiliently deal with failures.